# Bash script for update multiple database with multiple file

Tags: mysql, sql, database, bash

I need to create a script for the updating of multiple database with different files.
Follows the description of the current process:

```
show database;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| Audi               |
| Bmw                |
| Ferrari            |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
+--------------------+
```

for each database I have a sql file, like:

```
update_Audi.sql
update_Bmw.sql
update_Ferrari.sql
```

and I use this method:

```
mysql -uroot -pxxxxx Audi < /path_to_/update_Audi.sql
mysql -uroot -pxxxxx Bmw < /path_to_/update_Bmw.sql
mysql -uroot -pxxxxx Ferrari < /path_to_/update_Ferrari.sql
```

this is just an example, but we have over 50 databases for each brand....

sometimes I have a generic file for all database like all_db.sql. And I use this procedure:

```
mysql -uroot -pxxxxx Audi < /path_to_/all_db.sql
mysql -uroot -pxxxxx Bmw < /path_to_/all_db.sql
mysql -uroot -pxxxxx Ferrari < /path_to_/all_db.sql
```

When I want to import more than one file, I need to associate a specifc file "ex audi" to the proper database:

```
mysql -uroot -pxxxxx Audi < /path_to_/update_Audi.sql
```

How I can automatically select the file "update_Audi.sql" to import it into its database "Audi"?

Now, I need to import the same file into several databases, How may I do it?

I have tried to do it, but I have stopped because I don't know how to continue...
Here is the incomplete bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash 
MyUSER="root"     # USERNAME
MyPASS="xxxxx"       # PASSWORD
MyHOST="localhost"          # Hostname
#Autodetected via which command    
MYSQL="$(which mysql)"
#Gethostname                                          
HOST="$(hostname)"
#Date
NOW="$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")"

# Store list of databases
DBS=""
#I dont know to do it...
SINGLE_FILE="path_to_file"
MULTIPLE_FILE="Multiple file path"

# Exclude these databases
IGGY="mysql information_schema performance_schema"


# Get all database list first
DBS="$($MYSQL -u$MyUSER -p$MyPASS -h$MyHOST -Bse 'show databases')"

for db in $DBS
do
    skipdb=-1
    if [ "$IGGY" != "" ];
    then
        for i in $IGGY
        do
              [ "$db" == "$i" ] && skipdb=1 || :
              done
    fi

    if [ "$skipdb" == "-1" ] ; then

        #For single File to import
        $MYSQL -u $MyUSER -h $MyHOST -p$MyPASS $db < $SINGLE_FILE
        #For multiple file to import
        $MYSQL -u $MyUSER -h $MyHOST -p$MyPASS $db < $MULTIPLE_FILE

    fi
done
```

Comment: I would rather think that one single database for all brands would be enough. There's the concept of tables ...

Comment: mysql and sql-server are not the same RDBMS.

Comment: for Vmai, I used the brand of the car for better understanding, but the cars are missing anything, are different databases that sometimes they need different updates, and other times they need a single update. Is the same software, where each database is an individual customer.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do it in one while loop:

```
$MYSQL -N -u"$MyUSER" -h"$MyHOST" -p"$MyPASS" -e 'show databases' | \
  grep -v 'mysql\|information_schema\|performance_schema'         | \
while read -r db; do
      single_file="/path_to_/update_$db.sql"
      multiple_file=/path_to_/all_db.sql
      [ -f "$single_file" ] && $MYSQL -u"$MyUSER" -h"$MyHOST" -p"$MyPASS" "$db" <"$single_file"
      [ -f "$multiple_file" ] && $MYSQL -u"$MyUSER" -h"$MyHOST" -p"$MyPASS" "$db" <$multiple_file
done
```